# How to solve "VALUE BELOW WAS EVALUATED JUST NOW" in angular

Tags: angular

Please Help i am looping through subscribe and then storing data in an array but the result is showing empty array

below is image

[image: console output]

```js
let pid = this._commonFn.getDataFromLocalStorage("pid");
let filteredData: any = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }];
Promise.all(filteredData.map((d) => {
    this._productService.getRdaData(pid, d.id).subscribe((resp: any) => {
      if (resp.success && "data" in resp) {
        resp.data.forEach((element) => {
          allNutrientData.push(element);
        });
      }
    });
  })
).then((result) => console.log(allNutrientData));
```

or

```js
let filteredData: any = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }, { id: 4 }];
filteredData.map((d) => {
  this._productService.getRdaData(pid, d.id).subscribe((resp: any) => {
    if (resp.success && "data" in resp) {
      resp.data.forEach((element) => {
        allNutrientData.push(element);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

i am getting "VALUE BELOW WAS EVALUATED JUST NOW"

Comment: This message is because the `console.log` is happening before the array is changed from the callback in the subscription to the api call, but when you expand the array in the console, it will print what the array holds "now", not when it was logged originally.

Comment: I know this..but how i can solve this...

Comment: `this._productService.getRdaData(pid, d.id)` returns an observable, not a promise, so you can use RxJS to do the data collection instead of `Promise.all`.

Comment: Rxjs which operator could you guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing to note is that `this._productService.getRdaData(pid, d.id)` returns an RxJS Observable, and not a Promise. This means we can use RxJS to handle these results instead of doing it through `Promise.all`. This is a bit tricky if you are used to handling these problems using promises. Using observables to handle this problem reads quite a bit differently.

```js
// first, convert the array into a stream of items
from(filteredData).pipe(
  // map items to the request observable, maintaining order (like Promise.all)
  concatMap(d => (
    this._productService.getRdaData(pid, d.id)
  )),
  // map responses to the data
  map(resp => {
    if (resp.success && "data" in resp) {
      return resp.data;
    }
  }),
  // filter out empty responses
  filter(data => data !== undefined),
  // collect the data as an array ([[data1, data2], [data3, data4]...]
  toArray()
  // use concat to flatten the array
  // in this callback is where you can operate on the final data
).subscribe(data => console.log([].concat(...data)))
```

Comment: thanks...buddy ....it worked, and the problem resolved now